# Изменение подписки на событие кнопок в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

**Описание задачи:**

Есть кнопка "Начать поиск", при нажатии на которую, запускается поиск. После этого кнопка меняет текст на "Остановить поиск", и если нажать, поиск останавливается.

Думаю реализовать это так:по нажатии кнопки подписывать её на разные обработчики. Но не понимаю как это сделать.

Есть триггер, который позволяет менять св-ва, но не подпись на событие.

**Вопрос:** может есть более правильный способ?

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего, наверное, положить *две* кнопки, одну на другую. Вторая пусть будет скрытой. При нажатии на первую кнопку скрывайте её, и показывайте вторую кнопку. Это можно сделать как через триггеры, так и через привязку к свойству VM. Или даже вручную из code-behind, если хочется.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать следующее:

Каждая кнопка имеет свойство Content, который изначально инициализируется как textblock. Нам ничто не мешает сделать следующее:

```
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button.Content>
            <TextBlock Name="tb"></TextBlock>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
```

Теперь мы можем обращаться к этому TextBlock через код C#.

```
    bool flag = true;//Флаг нажатия на кнопку
    public void ChangeText() //метод изменения текста в TextBlock-е кнопки
    {
        if (flag == false) //Если флаг ложный
        {
            flag = true;//меняем значение
            tb.Text = "Начать поиск";//Меняем текст в соответствии с флагом
        }
        else//иначе
        {
            flag = false;//меняем значение
            tb.Text = "Остановить поиск";//Меняем текст в соответствии с флагом
        }
    }
    //----------------------
    private void bt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)//событие клика на кнопку
    {
        ChangeText();//вызов метода
    }
```